# Making a random string lower case

Tags: java, substring, uppercase, lowercase

I need to create a string of three random capital letters and three random digits, and output the result, which I have done. 
Next I need to make this whole string lower case, output the result, then make only the first character upper case and output the result. I've been trying to use `substring()`, but it isn't compiling and I'm not too sure how to use `substring()` with random generator. Here is what I have written and it would be great if i could get some help.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomString
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  Random generator = new Random();

       int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(2);
       char randomChar = (char)('A');
       System.out.print("A random string is " + randomChar);

       randomNumber = generator.nextInt(26);
       randomChar = (char)('A' + randomNumber);
       System.out.print(randomChar);

       randomNumber = generator.nextInt(26);
       randomChar = (char)('A' + randomNumber);
       System.out.print(randomChar);

       randomNumber = generator.nextInt(10);
       System.out.print(randomNumber);

       randomNumber = generator.nextInt(10);
       System.out.print(randomNumber);

       randomNumber = generator.nextInt(10);
       System.out.println(randomNumber);

    }
}
```

Comment: `Character.toLowerCase((char)('A' + randomNumber))`

Comment: You are not using strings

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get the string representation of the number
String sRandomNumber = Integer.toString(randomNumber);

// Convert to lower case
sRandomNumber = sRandomNumber.toLowerCase();

// Print it
System.out.println("In Lower Case: " + sRandomNumber);

// Make first char upper case
sRandomNumber = sRandomNumber.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + sRandomNumber.substring(1);

// Print it again
System.out.println("With 1st char upper case: " + sRandomNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way the string is crates is irrevant. Given any string, to capitalise the first letter, and lowercase the rest:

```
str = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // create a string of 3 random capital letters
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        sb.append((char)('A' + random.nextInt(26)));
    }
    // and 3 random digits
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        sb.append(random.nextInt(10));
    }
    // output the result
    System.out.println(sb);
    // make this whole string lower case and output the result
    String lowerCase = sb.toString().toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(lowerCase);
    // make only the first character upper case and output the result
    System.out.println(lowerCase.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + lowerCase.substring(1));
```